# python3: can json be decoded as tuple?

Tags: python, json

```
import json
t = (((9, 1, 4),), (), ((14, 5, 10),), ((0, 4, 5),))
j = json.dumps(t)
x = json.loads(j)
print(t) # (((9, 1, 4),), (), ((14, 5, 10),), ((0, 4, 5),))
print(x) # [[[9, 1, 4]], [], [[14, 5, 10]], [[0, 4, 5]]]
```

How I can decode directly from the json.loads() a json string as a (hierarchically deep) tuple?

I know that json encoding saves both tuples and lists as "arrays" but,  actually, my immutable "t" variable is very big and read-only thus the tuple style (as far as i know) is faster and more compact in memory than in list style.

Ideas? thanks!

Comment: Do you control the creation of the json, or just the loading part?

Comment: yes, i can control both encoding and decoding

Comment: are you sure you need json? can't you use pickle instead to preserve the python variable types?

Comment: unfortunately json is a constraint as data should be readable by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSON** is the short form of **JavaScript Object Notation** and in JavaScript there is data structure called **array** and to define arrays we use brackets `[` `]`  not parentheses `(` `)` like tuple in Python.

So whenever you will try to convert tuples to strings `json.dumps()`, it will be internally changed to array form like the one in **JavaScript** and list in **Python** with brackets `[` `]` around it.

```
import json
t = (((9, 1, 4),), (), ((14, 5, 10),), ((0, 4, 5),))

j = json.dumps(t)
x = json.loads(j)
print(t) # (((9, 1, 4),), (), ((14, 5, 10),), ((0, 4, 5),))
print(x) # [[[9, 1, 4]], [], [[14, 5, 10]], [[0, 4, 5]]]
```

If your intension is to convert **tuples** to **strings** and again from that string representation to real **Python** object (here it's **tuple**) then here is the solution.

```
j2 = str(t) 
x2 = eval(j2) 
print(j2) # (((9, 1, 4),), (), ((14, 5, 10),), ((0, 4, 5),))
print(x2) # (((9, 1, 4),), (), ((14, 5, 10),), ((0, 4, 5),))
```

Comment: wow! I hope that eval() is enough efficient, that's a great solution anyway! :-)

Comment: Make sure you understand the risks of eval() - read the docs

Comment: Yeah, that's right, it evaluates string expressions too. Apart from that other also. Finally providing the Python object by evaluating strings. Thank you.

Comment: A better option is to use [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) and [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). That's because `repr()` provides detail on the object when there is no literal `str` representation and `literal_eval()` performs a secure `eval` operation.